# Pass an audio file through segue

Tags: swift

I am stuck up with passing an audio file to second view controller. My code is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class recordSoundsViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

var audioRecorder: AVAudioRecorder!
var recordedAudioURL: URL!

@IBOutlet weak var tapToRecord: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var recording: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var stopRecording: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    stopRecording.isEnabled = false
}

// when record audio is pressed
@IBAction func recordAudio(_ sender: Any) {
    tapToRecord.text = "Recording in progress"
    stopRecording.isEnabled = true
    recording.isEnabled = false

// recording audio

    let dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory,.userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let recordingName = "recordedVoice.wav"
    let pathArray = [dirPath, recordingName]
    let filePath = URL(string: pathArray.joined(separator: "/"))
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .defaultToSpeaker)

    try! audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(url: filePath!, settings: [:])
    audioRecorder.delegate = self
    audioRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
    audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    audioRecorder.record()

}
// when stop button pressed
@IBAction func stopRecord(_ sender: Any) {
     tapToRecord.text = "Tap to Record"
    recording.isEnabled = true
    stopRecording.isEnabled = false
    audioRecorder.stop()
    let audiosession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    try! audiosession.setActive(false)
}

   func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(_ recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {
    if flag {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "stopRecording", sender: audioRecorder.url)
    } else {
        print("recording was not successful")
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "stopRecording" {
        var playSoundsVC = segue.destination as! playSoundsViewController
        let recordedAudioURL = sender as! URL
        playSoundsVC.recordedAudioURL = recordedAudioURL
    }
}
```

The line **playSoundsVC.recordedAudioURL = recordedAudioURL** throws error:

> Value of type 'playSoundsViewController' has no member 'recordedAudioURL"

Can anyone please point out the error?

Comment: You need to share the code for the destination view controller. How can you expect us to help without that code?

Comment: `playSoundsViewController` is your class. Fix it so it has the needed property.

Answer (score 2):

You must first create the `recordedAudioURL` property in the destination view controller if you want to assign it a value. Therefore:

```
class playSoundsViewController: UIViewController {
    var recordedAudioURL: URL?
}
```

Now you can give it a value.